# Pass Microsoft Edge traffic through proxifer

Tags: windows-10, socks-proxy, socks, microsoft-edge

I just installed Windows 10, and it seems that Proxifer can not capture and pass Microsoft Edge traffic through my SOCKS server. It doesn't capture anything.
While Internet Explorer's traffic still  goes through proxifier.

Any fix for this?

Comment: Same issue. No solution....

Comment: this also happens for Microsoft Store and similar apps

Comment: I am using Proxifier 3.29 too but still have this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install **Fiddler** (I have tested with 4.5.1 )
2. in **Tools** -> **Win8 Loopback Exceptions**

[image]

3. Check all or just the apps you like from the list

[image]

4. Click **Save Changes** (note: dialogue will be open after that)
5. now , you should see that all the traffic is from fiddler to targets
   you anticipate